# Efficient query to filter for list of values across columns/distinct rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL Server version is 2016+/Azure SqlDb (flexible if additive, compatible with both, forward-compatible).

Use case is API users sending a single-column list of values to filter some target table. The target table has 2-*n* columns whose values are unique across rows (maybe columns, doesn't matter) for the table/range being queried. (So far *n* <= 5, but that's a detail/not guaranteed.)

Here's a good-enough sample table DDL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SomeTable')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (
        ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) not null PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
      , NaturalKey1 nvarchar(10) not null UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
      , NaturalKey2 nvarchar(10) not null UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
      , NaturalKey3 nvarchar(10) not null UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
        );
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SomeTable)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable VALUES
        ('A', 'AA', 'ZZZZZ')
       ,('B', 'B', 'YYYYY')
       ,('C', 'CC', 'XXX')
       ,('D', 'DDD', 'WWWWW')
       ,('E', 'EEEE', 'V')
       ,('F', 'FF', 'UUUUUUUUU')
       ,('G', 'GGGGGGGG', 's')
       -- lots more
        ;
END

SELECT * FROM dbo.SomeTable;

-- DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

Assumptions are that all `NaturalKey` columns are of same type (probably `nvarchar`); filtering happens db-side; and in as few steps as possible, ideally one execution, in a stored procedure. Parameter will be string list or TVP, doesn't matter really. Result will include all data in any row of `SomeTable` that matches any value on any column. Target table is of unknown size.

Here's an example parameter for our pal above:

```
DECLARE @filterValues nvarchar(1000) = 'DDD,XXX,E,HH,ok,whatever,YYYYY';
SELECT * FROM string_split(@filterValues, ',');
```

I know a couple ways to do this, and can imagine several more, so it's not that kind of stuck. I'll bet someone knows a better trick than either of the two I'll illustrate.

**Approach 1** Build a temp table updated for existence and join on it (concise and nice to audit, that's about it for pros)

```
DECLARE @filterValues nvarchar(1000) = 'DDD,XXX,E,HH,ok,whatever,YYYYY';

SELECT value AS InValue, CONVERT(int, null) AS IDMatch
INTO #filters
FROM string_split(@filterValues, ',');

UPDATE f
SET f.IDMatch = st.ID
FROM #filters AS f
    INNER JOIN dbo.SomeTable AS st ON f.InValue IN (st.NaturalKey1, st.NaturalKey2, st.NaturalKey3);

SELECT * FROM #filters; -- Audit

SELECT st.* FROM #filters AS f INNER JOIN dbo.SomeTable AS st ON f.IDMatch = st.ID;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#filters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #filters;
```

**Approach 2** Unpivot `SomeTable` (I like the nifty [cross apply trick](https://sqlstudies.com/2013/05/20/the-many-uses-of-cross-apply/)) and just join (at scale there be ogres methinks)

```
SELECT 
        st.*
FROM 
    dbo.SomeTable AS st
    CROSS APPLY (VALUES (st.NaturalKey1)
                      , (st.NaturalKey2)
                      , (st.NaturalKey3)
                ) AS nk(Val)
    INNER JOIN #filters AS f ON nk.Val = f.InValue;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#filters') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #filters;
```

*Is there a question in our future*

Works is better than doesn't work, but looking for better/more efficient/more scalable methods from the T-SQL gurus. Unknown dimensions in columns and rows, response time is an SLA, filter size may or may not be capped. Bonus points if this ports neatly from `SomeTable` to `SomeTableVersionN`. (No dynamic SQL in an API.)

Could be dupe question, couldn't find it, pointing that out is just fine thank you.

Comment: You are using  UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED constraint on each column separately which mean that you might have the same value in two different rows in different columns. For example you can add this row to the sample: `INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable VALUES ('DDD', 'Ronen', 'Ariely')`. When you do so, then your temporarily table does not fit, since it includes only one row for each value in @filterValues. It will not be filled with the information of the last row which I added. Your basic approach is wrong (hope explanation is clear - hard to explain  in stackoverflow poor comment without image and code.

Comment: In general, I would not use temporarily table in this case. There is no reason to write the data in the disk. temp tables can be useful when we are required to transform or modify the big datasets and we want to index for example the data after modified. In this case, you can simply use CTE for example.

Comment: @RonenAriely that is unrelated to my question. It is a test table to illustrate a filtering point (and I wouldn't be validating data on an INSERT anyway).

Comment: @RonenAriely Also, you're assuming a fixed use case, instead of this simplified test. If, say, the requirement evolves to "... and return all the unmatched filter values separately", the temp table is not that bad at all.